# Let {$c_1$,$c_2$, , , , , $c_n$} and {$d_1$, $d_2$, , , , , $d_n$} be non-zero real numbers and let $a_{ij}$ = $c_id_j$ . how to find rank of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {$c_1$,$c_2$, , , , , $c_n$} and {$d_1$, $d_2$, , , , , $d_n$} be non-zero real numbers and let $a_{ij}$ = $c_id_j$ .
how do I find the rank of the matrix $A$ =$a_{ij}$

Somebody please give me some hint so that I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use elementary row operations to find the rank.

As each $c_i\neq0$ divide $i$th row by $c_i$ and proceed.
Also note that each entry of the matrix is nonzero as $d_j\neq0 \forall j$

Comment: rank of the matrix is $1$ ?

Comment: Yes correct. Rank is 1.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Each column of $A$ is a multiple of $c$, hence $Ax$ is a multiple of $c$ for all $x$. Hence the rank is at most $1$. Since $A$ is not the zero matrix, the rank is at least $1$.